# Expand Textfield if available space, set minHeight with scroll if not

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a Column indide a Scaffold, and one of the Column's children is a TextField. I'd like the Textfield to expand and take all the available space, but if there is not enough space (basically when the keyboard shows up), I want the Textfield to be 3 lines height min and the Column to be scrollable so the focus on the Textfield works as intended.

I've tried a lot of different widgets, like Expand, IntrinsicHeight, LayoutBuilder, ConstrainedBox, SingleChildScrollView...
But none of the tested combination did work as expected...

The SingleChildScrollView page did help me a lot but none of the example match my situation :
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Some\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nlong\ntext"),
          RaisedButton(child: Text("Some button")),
          Text("Second line"),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              //Use the expand parameter instead of padding + maxLines, once released : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27205
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 30),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Message...",
                ),
                maxLength: 500,
                maxLengthEnforced: true,
                maxLines: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: _send,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

With that code the first part works fine : when not keyboard is shown, the Textfield is expanded as expected. 
But when the keyboard shows up, the layout overflow (because there is no SingleChildScrollView).

EDIT : the new TextField.extends property helped a bit but didn't solved my issue...

Comment: you can use listview widget inside the column so the layout scroll behaves like listview when a keyboard is showing up and use children widget inside the listview hope this helps...

Comment: OK but how can you tell a child of a ListView to grow as big as the viewport allow ?